# How to configure same origin for apex (example.com) and subdomain (www.example.com) - aws Route53 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, serverless, amazon-route53

I can redirect the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com using CNAME or A record in route53 but the problem is I want single origin (example.com) in both cases because my api only allow origin example.com, so if I use [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in the browser my api doesnt recognize it and throws cors error.

Is there any way to configure this in such a way that in both cases origin header remains same (if I use [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the orgin header becomes example.com so that i dont get cors error)

Comment: Why is it a problem to set allow-origins header?

Comment: I want to avoid the logic of validating allowed origins in the lambda, Looking for a better way to achieve this. Allow origins header only takes a * wild card or single url

Comment: Route 53 does not support redirects as some other DNS services do. So if you don't want to do it "properly" with allow origins response header, I think the only option is Route53+S3 as pointed out by @jellycsc.

Answer (score 0):

A DNS record is **not** a redirect. A redirect means when the user visits `www.example.com`, a `301` status code is returned with the `Location` header set to the URL of the domain `example.com`. You can do this by using [S3 static website hosting with webpage redirect configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html) + CloudFront to enable HTTPS.